# Which propositional logics do you get by taking the class of Boolean algebras and adding "weak negation"?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

**Which propositional logics do you get by taking the class of Boolean algebras as a semantics and adding strong negation?**

I've encountered weak negation in unrelated contexts before as a unary connective that *exchanges designated and undesignated truth values*, so I'm curious what happens if you staple it to a well-known algebraic semantics.

---

Let $\mathsf{I}(\varphi)$ denote the interpretation of $\varphi$. Let $X$ be a set and $\Lambda$ be the partially ordered set $(2^X, \subset)$.

- $ \mathsf{I}(a)$ is the interpretation of $a$ when $a$ is a propositional variable.
- $ \mathsf{I}(a \land b)$ is $\mathsf{I}(a) \cap \mathsf{I}(b)$.
- $ \mathsf{I}(a \lor b)$ is $\mathsf{I}(a) \cup \mathsf{I}(b)$.
- $\mathsf{I}(\lnot a)$ is $X \setminus \mathsf{I}(a)$. This is ordinary negation.
- $\mathsf{I}(!a)$ is $\varnothing$ if $\mathsf{I}(a)$ is $X$, otherwise $\mathsf{I}(a)$ is $X$. This is weak negation. It exchanges designated and undesignated truth values.

If $X$ is $\{e\}$, then this semantics reduces to classical logic and $\lnot$ and $!$ are indistinguishable.

By a theorem cited [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2648840) and discussed more generally in [this article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/#AlgeSema), the semantics obtained using *the class of Boolean algebras* is the same as the one obtained from using $\{\varnothing, \{e\}\}$ alone.

However, adding *weak negation* essentially on a whim is enough to make the resulting semantics non-classical.

The following is a theorem of classical logic because the two connectives have the same meaning in that setting, and a theorem in the Boolean algebra semantics because $\mathsf{I}(a)$ must be $\varnothing$ when $\mathsf{\lnot a}$ is $X$.

$$ \frac{\lnot a}{! a} $$

However, the following is a theorem of classical logic only.

$$ \frac{! a}{\lnot a} $$

The following inference rule also fails in the $!$-setting.

$$ \frac{a \lor b \;\;\text{and}\;\; !a}{b} \;\; \text{is not a valid inference rule} $$

Comment: By $0$ and $1$ do you mean $\varnothing$ and $X$? It seems like the values of $\mathsf{I}$ should be subsets of $X$...

Comment: @MishaLavrov, yes the truth values are the subsets of $X$. I used $0$ and $1$ since I think those names are standard for the smallest and largest element in a Boolean algebra, but that's not consistent with the rest of the question so I changed it.

Comment: If $\lnot a$ entails $!a$ but not conversely, shouldn't $!a$ be called "weak negation"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Thanks, that's a good point. I wasn’t sure what to call it. Ideally I’d like an adjective that conveys its relationship with the designated truth values. I’ll rename it to weak negation.